# Passing context to a dynamically added child in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

I'm trying to pass context to a React component, but because I am testing with Enzyme, I'd like to add the component to its parent dynamically so I can examine its state. The test looks like this:

```
describe('<BeaconConfig />', () => {
  it('inherits the config from BeaconConfig', () => {
    mount(<BeaconConfig persistent><div id="parent"></div></BeaconConfig>, { attachTo: document.body });
    const wrapper = mount(<Beacon/>, { attachTo: document.getElementById('parent') });
    expect(wrapper.state('persistent')).to.be(true);
  });
});
```

The test fails because the `persistent` property of the `Beacon` component's state is `undefined`, although it should be inherited from `BeaconConfig` via context.

When I try putting `Beacon` directly inside the JSX when I mount `BeaconConfig` then it works fine, but in this case Enzyme won't let me get at the `Beacon` component state since it isn't the root.

Is it normal that React isn't propagating the context to my component when I add it dynamically to its parent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the complete test I ended up using:

```
describe('Context', () => {
  let wrapper;
  let parent;
  const open = stub().returns({});
  const mockIndexedDB = { open };
  const config = mount(<BeaconConfig persistent position="bottom" indexedDB={mockIndexedDB} />);

  beforeEach(() => {
    parent = document.createElement('div');
    document.body.appendChild(parent);
    wrapper = mount(<Beacon>some text</Beacon>, {
      attachTo: parent,
      context: config.instance().getChildContext()
    });
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    wrapper.detach();
    document.body.removeChild(document.body.firstChild);
  });

  it('overrides the default values with the context if any', () => {
    expect(wrapper.state('persistent')).to.be(true);
    expect(wrapper.state('position')).to.be('bottom');
    expect(open.calledOnce).to.equal(true);
  });
});
```

@STRML had a good suggestion but I don't think that it is possible to access the state of a non-root component.

Instead I instantiate `BeaconConfig` in isolation and grab it's child context, passing that manually to `Beacon` using the `options` parameter of `mount`. This tests that `BeaconConfig` creates the right child context and that `Beacon` uses the context correctly. It doesn't test that `BeaconConfig` passes the config down to `Beacon` when the latter is a descendant, but we can presumably take that for granted since it is basic React functionality.

Answer (score 1):

It is normal that React isn't propagating the context - it doesn't look at the DOM and diff it with its VDOM in that way.

You'll want make it a child in the initial mount, and use the `.find()` or `.children()` methods of the MountWrapper ([docs](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/mount.md)) to dig through the children, find the Beacon and do your assertions.

Comment: I see what you mean about the VDOM diff. Just attaching a component to an element that happens to be rendered as a child of the top-level component doesn't make it part of that component tree.

The problem with the approach you suggest is that Enzyme won't let you view the state of a non-root component, at least I couldn't figure out how to do it last time I checked.

Comment: See https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/src/ReactWrapper.js#L529